# Visual Studio - When I press enter I want to maintain the spacing of the previous row

Tags: visual-studio, spacing, enter

I've a question regarding the Visual Studio program, I'm creating a .sln project and in the part where I'm editing the different code I want to know if there's anyway that when I press enter the next code line maintains my spacing. Example:

```
const GLfloat vertices[] = {    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
                                -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
```

If I have the mouse located in the last comma (,) I want that if I press "enter" the cursor is located just below the -1.0. So it maintain the spacing of the previous row.

Is there an easy way to do this? Like pressing "enter" + "something"?